# VS 2017 - VSTS migrating from individual accounts to Azure AD authentication

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

We have recently switched our VSTS account from individual accounts to Azure AD (we have set it up prior to having an Azure AD).

All works ok, except for connection from VS 2017. Every time I try to push or pull from the VSTS git - I get a username / password prompt (looks like a VSTS login screen).

After entering username and password it error out, with the following error appearing in VS output window:

```
Pushing master
Error: cannot spawn /c/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2017/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
could not read Username for 'https://companyname.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled
Pushing to https://companyname.visualstudio.com/_git/Companyname.ApplicationFramework
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the specific version of VS 2017 do you use? There is a similar issue with VS 15.7.x.  Please refer to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/290783/git-askpassexe-no-such-file-or-directory.html  for details.

Just try below things to fix the issue:

- Try to remove
  `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache` file
  and then re-enter credentials.
- Download the latest version of the git credential manager, and
  copying the contents of the zip file [gcmw-v1.14.0.zip](https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/42456996/0c970da8-9cbb-11e8-8872-453094b73ffa?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20180903%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180903T030506Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=0d3b3e929dabc44704824f133c1de9aabbc3008f1094c36f2232e7bf47b454c0&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dgcmw-v1.17.1.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream)
  (from[GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.17.1)) to below path:

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team
  Explorer\Git\mingw32\libexec\git-core`
- Re-install Git-for-Windows

  1. Delete this folder (backing it up in case you need to restore it):

     `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team
     Explorer\Git`
  2. Uninstall all versions of Git via Control Panel / Uninstall a
     program.
  3. Run the Visual Studio 2017 installer and modify the install to
     remove `Git For Windows`.
  4. [Download the latest version of Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and install it.
  5. Run the Visual Studio 2017 installer again and modify the install to
     add `Git For Windows` again.